# how do I optimize a nested for loop?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, for-loop

I have a distance matrix `BD_D_R` that contains the distance of each element of the main matrix `psnr_bitrate` to other elements. each time we have 6 clusters of main elements and we have to find an element that has the lowest distance from all other elements in the cluster. for this aim, I have to run three nested for loops to find the element for each cluster which is very time-consuming. is it a way to find this point for each cluster instead of using these for loops and calculating the distance again? we calculate the distances one time and the number of elements is high and it is time-consuming. `psnr_bitrate` is an array with size (700,6) and `BD_D_R` is an array with size 700x700. each cluster maybe has 200 or fewer members. if we could extract the index of elements in each cluster and calculate the distance using a distance matrix without for loops, I think it works, but I do not know how can I do this using python code.
I used the following code for updating the points. As you can see I implement Kmeans clustering with my own distance function BD_rate and the bottleneck of the code is during updating the centroid when I have to calculate the distance of each node with all other nodes in each cluster. do you have any suggestions to do this part without using nested for loops?

```
    #####################################################################################
def centroid_initiation(centroid,K,label,psnr_bitrate):
    array_part=np.array_split(psnr_bitrate,K)
    if label==0:
       for i in range(K):
           tmp=array_part[i]
           tmp=tmp[np.lexsort(np.fliplr(tmp).T)]# sort based on first column without chnaging other columns
           centroid[i,:]=tmp[int(np.floor(len(array_part[i])/2)),:] 
       return(centroid)
    else:
        rnd=random.sample(range(0, psnr_bitrate.shape[0]), K)
        centroid=psnr_bitrate[rnd]
        return centroid
    
###################################################################################

def kmeans_BD(psnr_bitrate,K,centroid):
    m=psnr_bitrate.shape[0]#number of samples
    n=psnr_bitrate.shape[1]#number of bitrate
    
    # creating an empty array
    BD=np.zeros((m,K))
    #weight of BD_rate
    wr=0.5
    #weight of BD_Q
    wq=0.5
    n_itr=1000
    # finding distance between for each centroid
    for itr in range(n_itr):
        for k in range(K):
            for i in range(len(psnr_bitrate)):
                # print(i)
                tmp_return=BD_RATE('VMAF_Y',rate,centroid[k,:],rate,psnr_bitrate[i,:])
                if tmp_return==np.NINF:
                    BD[i,k]=np.inf  
                else:
                    BD[i,k]=np.abs(tmp_return)
                # a=BD_RATE('VMAF_Y',rate,psnr_bitrate[i,:],rate,centroid[k,:])
                # BD_R=bd_rate(rate,psnr_bitrate[i,:],rate,centroid[k,:],i)
                # BD_Q=bd_PSNR(rate,psnr_bitrate[i,:],rate,centroid[k,:],i)
                # BD[i,k]=wr*BD_R+wq*BD_Q
        #remove rows which all columns has inf value and put them in a new cluster
        finding_non_infValue=np.asarray(BD[BD.min(axis=1) != np.inf])
        indx_removed=np.where([BD.min(axis=1) == np.inf])[1]
        indx_nonremoved=np.where([BD.min(axis=1) != np.inf])[1]
        removed_member=[psnr_bitrate[x] for x in indx_removed]
        saved_member=[psnr_bitrate[x] for x in indx_nonremoved]
        
        # storing the minimum value we have computed  
        minimum=np.argmin(finding_non_infValue,axis=1)+1
        minimum_distance=finding_non_infValue.min(axis=1)
        minimum_merge=np.zeros((minimum.shape[0],2))
        minimum_merge[:,0]=minimum
        minimum_merge[:,1]=minimum_distance       
        # computing the mean of separated clusters
        clusters={}
        for itr1 in range(K):
            clusters[itr1+1]=np.array([]).reshape(n,0)
        
        # assigning of clusters to points
        for itr1 in range(len(saved_member)):
            clusters[minimum[itr1]]=np.c_[clusters[minimum[itr1]],saved_member[itr1]]
        for itr1 in range(K):
            clusters[itr1+1]=clusters[itr1+1].T
        clusters_tmp=np.zeros((K,1))
        for itr1 in range(K):
            if clusters[itr1+1].shape[0]!=[]:
                clusters_tmp[itr1]=clusters[itr1+1].shape[0]
            else:
                clusters_tmp[itr1]=-1
        num=(clusters_tmp==-1).sum()#[itr4 for itr4, x in clusters_tmp if x == -1]
        if num==K:
            centroid=centroid_initiation(centroid,K,label,psnr_bitrate)
        else:
            if num>0:
                tmp_idx=0
                while num>0:
                    indx=np.where([clusters_tmp ==-1 ])[1]+1 #index of no member cluster
                    H_cluster=np.argmax(clusters_tmp)+1# index of cluster with more members
                    tmp=np.where(minimum_merge == max([i for i in minimum_merge if i[0]==H_cluster], key=lambda x : x[1]))
                    idx,=np.where(tmp[1]==1)
                    clusters[indx[tmp_idx]][0]=clusters[H_cluster][idx]#add member to other cluster
                    clusters[H_cluster]=np.delete(clusters[H_cluster],(idx),axis=0)#remove the member from main cluster
                    num-=1
                    tmp_idx+=1

        # computing mean and updating it
        for itr2 in range(K):
            tmp_cl=clusters[itr2+1]
            if len(tmp_cl)>1:
                BD_cent=np.zeros((len(tmp_cl),1))
                for itr3 in range(len(tmp_cl)):
                    sumv=0
                    for itr5 in range(len(tmp_cl)):
                        value=BD_RATE('VMAF_Y',rate,tmp_cl[itr3,:],rate,tmp_cl[itr5,:])
                        if value!=np.NINF:
                            sumv+=np.abs(value)
                        else:
                            sumv+=1000#for curve which have not overlap with others
                    BD_cent[itr3]=sumv/len(tmp_cl)
                
                new_centroid_index=np.argmin(BD_cent)
                centroid[itr2]=clusters[itr2+1][new_centroid_index]
                    # a=BD_RATE('VMAF_Y',rate,psnr_bitrate[i,:],rate,centroid[k,:])
                    # BD_R=bd_rate(rate,psnr_bitrate[i,:],rate,centroid[k,:],i)
                    # BD_Q=bd_PSNR(rate,psnr_bitrate[i,:],rate,centroid[k,:],i)
                    # BD[i,k]=wr*BD_R+wq*BD_Q
            # storing the minimum value we have computed           
    scaled_features = pd.DataFrame((psnr_bitrate))
    scaled_features['cluster'] =minimum
    pd.plotting.parallel_coordinates(scaled_features, 'cluster')

 psnr_bitrate=np.vstack([np.loadtxt(path, dtype='float') for path in glob.iglob(r'C:/Users/jamalm8/ffmpeg/UGCvideos/*.txt')])
#remove non monotonic curve 
itr=0  
m=len(psnr_bitrate)
while (itr<len(psnr_bitrate)):
    brqtypairs1=psnr_bitrate[itr,:]
    rd1_monotonic = all(x<y for x, y in zip(brqtypairs1, brqtypairs1[1:]))
    if (rd1_monotonic == False ):
        print (itr)
        psnr_bitrate=np.delete(psnr_bitrate, (itr),axis=0)
        itr=itr-1
    itr=itr+1

m=psnr_bitrate.shape[0]#number of samples
n=psnr_bitrate.shape[1]#number of bitrate
K=6 #number of cluster
rate=[1000,2000,3000,4000,5000,6000]
#firt initializaation of cluster centroid
#the median of each group is considered as centroid
array_part=np.array_split(psnr_bitrate,K)
centroid=np.zeros((K,6))
label=0
centroid=centroid_initiation(centroid,K,label,psnr_bitrate)
label+=1   
# rnd=random.sample(range(0, 638), K)
# centroid=psnr_bitrate[rnd]

# creating an empty array
#weight of BD_rate
wr=0.5
#weight of BD_Q
wq=0.5
kmeans_BD(psnr_bitrate, K, centroid)
```

Comment: What is your actual goal? I see k-means clustering; is that the goal?

Comment: executing Kmeans with my distance function instead of Euclidean distance.  and as I search on different sites they told me I can not use python Kmeans with my distance function and so I have to write it myself. but the problem is the part for updating the centroids based on my distance. is it a way to do this instead of using for loops?

Comment: @david your code is not working (`BD_RATE` is not defined, …) and is not reproducible. You must prepare a reproducible code, others can work on. I suggest you make the code very shorter as it was in the first edition of your post and prepare needed inputs by using `repr` or …. Just put that function you are saying will faced to bottleneck. You can put equivalent data as list or arrays instead the other functions, which are called by this function.